# Possible to set absolut line spacing using Google Docs API?

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm new at using Google Docs API and can't figure out if it is possible to set a fixed line spacing in my document. I want the spacing to stay fixed even if changing font and font size, like you can do in Microsoft Word by setting number of points and 'Exactly'.

I have tried to check the Google Docs API documentation without finding any solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think [UpdateParagraphStyleRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#UpdateParagraphStyleRequest) only accepts a relative value like 1.15 line spacing, so you could calculate the line spacing value based on the detected font size of each paragraph. Would require first getting the document data and parsing through it to find the indices and font sizes of paragraphs, to run through some function like this:

```
const createLineSpacingUpdateRequest = (fontSize, startIndex, endIndex) => {
  const TARGET_SPACING = 20;
  const lineSpacing = Math.round((TARGET_SPACING / fontSize) * 100);

  return {
    updateParagraphStyle: {
      range: {
        startIndex,
        endIndex,
      },
      paragraphStyle: {
        lineSpacing,
      },
      fields: '*',
    }
  };
}
```